# How can I use Babel Standalone with Flow

Tags: javascript, html, babeljs, flowtype

I am fully front-end web developer and I sometimes use TypeScript in IDEs. But TypeScript is strict and it needs npm and I don't have npm on my hosting (I don't want another one). So Flow with Babel Standalone is a good option. But how can I add Flow plugin?

Complete:

```html
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="______" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="flow-strip-types" src="script.js"></script>
```

view at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#docsNav